# sping gateway and spring data rest, rest link be rewrited to subservice remote address

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, gateway

when i use "spring gateway" and "spring data rest". request gateway distribute to my spring data rest project. but i got result link is spring data rest project remote address. i think is gateway remote address.

my gateway address is "http://192.168.1.112:8080"

my spring data rest project address is "http://192.168.1.112:8082/api"

so. i can request "http://192.168.1.112:8080/serviceId/foo/bar" to distribute. but response result's link has error

```
{
    "_links": {
        "containers": {
            "href": "http://192.168.1.112:8082/api/containers{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        }
}
```

i need so:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "containers": {
            "href": "http://192.168.1.112:8080/serviceId/api/containers{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        }
}
```

thanks

Comment: SDR will use the x-forwarded-for and x-forwarded-proto headers (if present) to construct the URLs. Some discussion here on these not being set in the gateway although that was last year and marked as fixed in v2.0.2: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/314

Comment: make sure to disable forward headers if you use x-forward headers. Forward headers have higher priority and x-forward will then be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

With spring cloud 2.0.

There is a statement that "x-forwarded-*" header is danger. So spring cloud doesn't resolve the "x-forwarded-*" header.

If you need you should register `ForwardedHeaderFilter` in spring web context.

Some code:

`/** * ForwardedHeader过滤器 * * @return ForwardedHeader过滤器 */ @Bean public FilterRegistrationBean forwardedHeaderFilter() { FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(); filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new ForwardedHeaderFilter()); filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE); return filterRegistrationBean; }`